# Any idea why google translate API doesn't return characters containing diacritics when API is called from a java app?

Tags: java, google-translate

I am trying to use the google translate public API endpoint to translate a handful of words  from english to romanian, and while doing this I've noticed that when I am calling this endpoint from by java application, the response is missing the characters containing diacritics.
eg:
for "delete" it returns " terge" instead of "șterge". The "ș" is missing from the google translate API response.

Google translate response content:

```
<span id="tw-answ-target-text"> terge</span>
```

Expected response content:

```
<span id="tw-answ-target-text">șterge</span>
```

It doesn't seem to be an encoding problem, as if I create a test endpoint on my end which returns "șterge", my java code is able to get the complete string back "șterge". Also I am not seeing any problems with asian languages like chinese and/or japanese.

If I'm sending the same translation request, from my browser, the "ș" char is being returned.

Could this be some kind of protection mechanism on Googles side? Not sure what else it could be... Any idea?

My java code looks something like below. I am running it on openJDK 17:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest.Builder;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;


public class TestTranslate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).build();
            String translatePayload = "async=translate,sl:en,tl:ro,st:delete,id:" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ",qc:true,ac:true,_id:tw-async-translate,_pms:s,_fmt:pc";
        
            Builder requestBuilder = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://www.google.com/async/translate"))
                .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        
            HttpRequest request = requestBuilder.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(translatePayload)).build();

            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println("=======================1");
            System.out.println(response.body());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("=======================2");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you running that? What's the value of `System.defaultCharset()`? What's returned by that request looks odd, if not wrong

Comment: @g00se Charset.defaultCharset() returns "UTF-8".  My app is a Spring boot app, running on a docker container: azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:17 . As I've mentioned it doesn't look like an encoding problem, at least not on my end. I've also tried to get the byte array from the httpclient and covert it to UTF-8 string, and I'm seeing the same behavior:  HttpResponse<byte[]> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());
String responseString = new String(response.body(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Comment: Specifying the charset utf-8 in the ofString method, has the same result:  HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

Comment: fwiw I get exactly the same thing. It's a space character. I don't know what this is, but the fact that it *starts* with `)]}'` doesn't fill me with confidence ;)

Comment: Those start characters can be seen in the google translate web page responses too. And there works OK. So I doubt is that.

Comment: What would that mean though? It looks like the *end* of some sort of json

Comment: Not sure what their role is...

Comment: And it *ends* with `3;[9]0;` How on earth would you use that?

Comment: I'm only interested in the translated text. I don't care about the rest of the elements. And to extract that I use a pattern matcher: Pattern.compile("<span id=\"tw-answ-target-text\">(.*?)<\\/span>");

Comment: Well the translated text is deficient. It has a space where the character you say should be present ought to be. It could be because the get request is not right